# nextAuth- signIn return only email

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

i use nextAuth and signIn.

I only get back to my email in the session without any other data that I need from the [...nextAuth]

response:

{"user":{"email":"xxx@xxx.com"},"expires":"2023-10-22T18:54:26.586Z"}

my [...nextAuth].js

```
import nextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { connecToDatabase } from "../../../lib/db";
import { verifyPassword } from "../../../lib/auth";
export default nextAuth({
    session:{
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    providers:[
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",

     async authorize(Credentials, req){
      const client = await  connecToDatabase();
        const usersCollection =client.db().collection('users');
    const user= await usersCollection.findOne({email: Credentials.email})
    if(!user){
        client.close();
        throw new Error('No user found');
           }
    const isValid= await verifyPassword(Credentials.password, user.password);

    if(!isValid){
        client.close();
        throw new Error('Could not log you in')
           }

      client.close();
      return{ email: user.email, adminType: user.adminType };
     }
     })

    ]
});
```

my admin js:
pages/admin.js:

```
import {signIn, signOut} from 'next-auth/react';
import {useSession} from 'next-auth/react'

 async function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(isLogin){
    const result = await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    });
```

Would appreciate help

Comment: make a jwt callback and return the adminType, then session callback and add this adminType to the user object